# При фокусе не появляется клавиатура на IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js

Такая проблема: нужно фокусить инпут и показывать клаву при инициализации страницы. Но проблема в том, что при программном взаимодействии клавиатура не показывается, а ждет пользовательских действий. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой. Существует ли какое-то решение?

Comment: Есть успехи? Такая же проблема.

Comment: Да! Все зависит от ситуации. Если нужно показать клаву при открытии страницы, то тут андроид и эпл запрещают вызывать клаву программно. Но если тебе нужно показать клаву после какого-то экшена юзера (но не фокус инпута)  [вот решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54424729/ios-show-keyboard-on-input-focus/55425845)